# Silverlight Telerik RadGridView - export to csv does not show all grid columns

Tags: silverlight, telerik-grid

When I use the "Export" functionality of a Telerik RadGridView control (silverlight), I do not get to see all the grid columns in the resulting csv.
I have seen that if I use the "GridViewDataColumn" it works fine.

However, if I use a "GridViewColumn" with CellTemplate and CellEditTemplate, the column does not appear in the generated csv file.

For e.g. In the following example, the columns Name and Rank gets exported as columns but the last column "Place" is not available. Please help...

```
<!-- This column works -->
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Rank" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Rank}">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Rank}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
      </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

<!-- This column does not work - not shown in the exported csv -->
<telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Place"
                                        IsReorderable="False"
                                        IsFilterable="False"
                                        UniqueName="MyPlace">
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Place}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Place}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellEditTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/export-functionality-of-radgridview-does-not-have-all-columns-in-the-resulting-csv.aspx) you cannot export GridViewColumn, and should use bounded GridViewDataColumn